# How to create a single function that covers all cases?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a begginer using JavaScript and I want to optimize the code creating a single function instead of repeat almost the same operations 20 times...

So I have 20 for loops like this:

```
// loop through the log array
for(var i = 0; i < textParsed.length; i++) {
    if (textParsed[i].includes("Action: Performing tests from category: Boot and services")){
        var content = document.createTextNode(textParsed[i]); // create a textnode to the document
        var li = document.createElement('li'); // create an arbitrary li element
        li.appendChild(content); // append the created textnode above to the li element
        ul.appendChild(li); // append the created li element above to the ul element
        for (var j = i+1; j < textParsed.length; j++) {
                if(textParsed[j].includes("Action: Performing")){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    content = document.createTextNode(textParsed[j]); // create a textnode to the document
                    var li2 = document.createElement('li'); // create an arbitrary li element
                    li2.appendChild(content); // append the created textnode above to the li element
                    ul.appendChild(li2); // append the created li element above to the ul element
                }
        }    
    }
}
div.appendChild(ul); // finally the ul element to the div with an id of placeholder

for(var i = 0; i < textParsed.length; i++) {
    if(textParsed[i].includes("Action: Performing tests from category: Accounting")){
        var content = document.createTextNode(textParsed[i]); // create a textnode to the document
        var li = document.createElement('li'); // create an arbitrary li element
        li.appendChild(content); // append the created textnode above to the li element
        ul2.appendChild(li); // append the created li element above to the ul element
        for (var j = i+1; j < textParsed.length; j++) {
                if(textParsed[j].includes("Action: Performing")){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    content = document.createTextNode(textParsed[j]); // create a textnode to the document
                    var li2 = document.createElement('li'); // create an arbitrary li element
                    li2.appendChild(content); // append the created textnode above to the li element
                    ul2.appendChild(li2); // append the created li element above to the ul element
                }
        } 
    }
}
div2.appendChild(ul2);

for(var i = 0; i < textParsed.length; i++) {
    if(textParsed[i].includes("Action: Performing tests from category: Users, Groups and Authentication")){
        var content = document.createTextNode(textParsed[i]); // create a textnode to the document
        var li = document.createElement('li'); // create an arbitrary li element
        li.appendChild(content); // append the created textnode above to the li element
        ul3.appendChild(li); // append the created li element above to the ul element
        for (var j = i+1; j < textParsed.length; j++) {
                if(textParsed[j].includes("Action: Performing")){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    content = document.createTextNode(textParsed[j]); // create a textnode to the document
                    var li2 = document.createElement('li'); // create an arbitrary li element
                    li2.appendChild(content); // append the created textnode above to the li element
                    ul3.appendChild(li2); // append the created li element above to the ul element
                }
        } 
    }
}
div3.appendChild(ul3);
```

Is there any way to create a function with only one for instead of create > 20 for statements with almost same code?

**There is only one small difference for every `for` statement: `ul` is increasing every time. **

Comment: This belongs on [CodeReview.se]

Comment: You're wrong about `only one small difference`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parcelling all this logic into a single function sounds a great idea!

I'd advise passing in the ul as a parameter to said function. You'd then have something along the lines of:

```
function loop(ul){
     // Add loop logic here
}
```

Your function calls will then look like this:

```
loop(ul);
loop(ul1);
loop(ul3);
// ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `includes` argument changes every loop.

So if you create an array with all these strings, you can iterate through.
Just don't forget to initialize your `ul` with `document.createElement('ul')` to get empty list at start of each outer loop iteration.

Assume you want it all to one div:

```
[
 'Action: Performing tests from category: Boot and services',
 // ...
].forEach(addListTo(div));

function addListTo(div) {
  return function(str) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    //.. filter and build your ul based on the str value
    div.appendChild(ul);
  }
}
```

Or you want to get list of `ul`s:

```
var ulList = strList.map(getUl);

function getUl(str) {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  //.. filter and build your ul based on the str value
  return ul;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a object that contains these ul's or if you create a one, you can access the ul's using index. f.eks.

```
ul_list = {
    ul1: {someobject},
    ul2: {someobject},
    ul3: {someobject}
}
```

these can be accessed using this notation

```
ul_list["ul1"]
```

In your foor loop you can then do this

```
ul_list["ul" + number_of_ul]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a function and pass the parameters into it

```
function appendChild(div, ul) {
    // loop through the log array
    for(var i = 0; i < textParsed.length; i++) {
        if (textParsed[i].includes("Action: Performing tests from category: Boot and services")){
            var content = document.createTextNode(textParsed[i]); // create a textnode to the document
            var li = document.createElement('li'); // create an arbitrary li element
            li.appendChild(content); // append the created textnode above to the li element
            ul.appendChild(li); // append the created li element above to the ul element
            for (var j = i+1; j < textParsed.length; j++) {
                if(textParsed[j].includes("Action: Performing")){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    content = document.createTextNode(textParsed[j]); // create a textnode to the document
                    var li2 = document.createElement('li'); // create an arbitrary li element
                    li2.appendChild(content); // append the created textnode above to the li element
                    ul.appendChild(li2); // append the created li element above to the ul element
                }
           }    
       }
    }
   div.appendChild(ul); 
}

appendChild(div, ul);
appendChild(div2, ul2);
appendChild(div3, ul3);
```